# c# Linq to xml - Extract parents of child element

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have this xml:

```
<Root>
  <RootKey>1</RootKey>
  <ChildL1>
    <ChildL1Key>12</ChildL1Key>
    <Child2>
      <Child2Key>TakeMe</Child2Key>
    </Child2>
    <Child2>
      <Child2Key>365</Child2Key>
    </Child2>
  </ChildL1>
  <ChildL1>
    <ChildL1Key>95</ChildL1Key>
    <Child2>
      <Child2Key>958</Child2Key>
    </Child2>
    <Child2>
      <Child2Key>574</Child2Key>
    </Child2>
  </ChildL1>
</Root>
```

I need to extract the the parents of the ***Child2*** where ***Child2Key*** == "TakeMe". The result would be:

```
<Root>
  <RootKey>1</RootKey>
  <ChildL1>
    <ChildL1Key>12</ChildL1Key>
    <Child2>
      <Child2Key>TakeMe</Child2Key>
    </Child2>
  </ChildL1>
</Root>
```

I can probably do it in 2 steps. Iterate through parent upwards from Child2 and get their keys, and in the next step remove the elements with other keys. I'd rather do it in one query if possible.

Comment: Why would the `ChildL1Key` element be included, and the `RootKey` element? Those aren't direct ancestors of `Child2Key`.

Comment: Because they are part of the parent of Child2 which as I said I need to extract. Thanks for the votedown.

Comment: @Yoav you need xml as output, or just data?

Comment: @Yoav: `RootKey` is *not* part of the parent of `Child2`, but the *other* `Child2` is. I hadn't voted your question down before, but now that it seems you have no intention of clarifying it, I will. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question. Currently it's unanswerably vague.

Comment: Not sure how I can be more explicit then giving the expected result. Note I referred to parents and not parent.

Comment: @Yoav my solution returns your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
xdoc.Descendants("Child2")
    .Where(c2 => c2.Element("Child2Key").Value != "TakeMe")
    .Remove();

xdoc.Descendants("ChildL1")
    .Where(c1 => !c1.Descendants("Child2").Any())
    .Remove();

// now xdoc contains what you need
string xml = xdoc.ToString();
```

First query removes all `Child2` nodes which does not match search condition.

Second query removes all `ChildL1` which do not have `Child2` nodes anymore.

**Special for LB**

```
xdoc.Descendants("ChildL1")            
    .Where(c1 => !c1.Descendants("Child2")
                    .Any(c2 => c2.Element("Child2Key").Value == "TakeMe"))
    .Concat(xdoc.Descendants("Child2")
                .Where(c2 => c2.Element("Child2Key").Value != "TakeMe"))
    .Remove();
```

Comment: `I can probably do it in 2 steps. ....... I'd rather do it in one query if possible.`

Comment: Read question carefully: I can **probably** do it in 2 steps. **Iterate through parent upwards from Child2 and get their keys, and in the next step remove the elements with other keys**. I'd rather do it in one query if possible. - I do this in one first step. Also it is not complete solution. OP needs 3rd step to remove ChildL1 nodes. Also this task is not effective to do in one step (if it possible)

Comment: No need to be rude, you do in one step?